# Retrieve elements from a list filter by Current User using JavaScript on SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm getting some issues trying to get the values on the list filter by the user. Right now i get a `view.getItems` is not a function", when i change them to `List.getItems('');` it work but not filter.

```
function sharePointReady() {
    var targetClientContext;
    var List;
    var view;

    targetClientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    List                = targetClientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My Recognitions');
    view                = List.get_views().getByTitle('CurrentUser');
    this.collList       = view.getItems("");

    //Get the list view and load it to client context and execute the batch  
    targetClientContext.load(collList);
    targetClientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}

var value = 0;
var counter = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    function onRequestSucceeded() {
        var listItemEnum = collList.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
            view = listItemEnum.get_current();
            console.log(view.get_item('ID'));
            console.log('Load ' + ++counter);
            value = view.get_item('Value');
            console.log(value);    
        }
        console.log('');
        console.log('Tu puntos son: ' + counter);
        document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = counter + ' Points';
    }
}

function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: there's a similar problem on SharePoint stack exchange here (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202705/how-to-filter-a-list-by-current-user-display-name ) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(sharePointReady, "sp.js");

function sharePointReady(){
    getItemsFromView("My Recognitions", "CurrentUser",
        function(items){
             for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count(); i++){
                 var item = items.get_item(i);
                 console.log(item.get_item('Title'));
             }
         },
         function(sender,args){ 
             console.log(args.get_message())
         }
    );
}

function getItemsFromView(listTitle, viewTitle,success,error){
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
    ctx.load(view,'ViewQuery');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            var viewQry = "<View><Query>" + view.get_viewQuery() + "</Query></View>";
            getItems(listTitle,viewQry,success,error);
        },
        error);
}

function getItems(listTitle, queryText,success,error) {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml(queryText);
    var items = list.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            success(items);
        },
        error
   );
}
</script>
```

In SharePoint 2013, if you only want to get list items created by current user, we can use REST API with $filter to achieve it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var listname = "My Recognitions";
    var currentUserId=_spPageContextInfo.userId
    var url = siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$filter=Author/Id eq "+currentUserId;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {       
            var items = data.d.results;
            $.each(items,function(index,item){
                console.log("Title:"+item.Title);
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a view of list items based on an existing view, you can grab the view's underlying CAML query XML through the `view.get_viewQuery()` method.

You can then feed that string into the View XML of a new `SP.CamlQuery` object which you can pass to `list.getItems()` to get the results.

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("My Recognitions");
 var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("CurrentUser");
 clientContext.load(view);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
      var query = view.get_viewQuery();
      var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
      camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
      var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
      clientContext.load(items);
      clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
           function(){
                 var itemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                 var counter = 0;
                 while(itemEnumerator.moveNext()){
                     var item = itemEnumerator.get_current();
                     console.log(item.get_item("ID"));
                     console.log('Load ' + ++counter);
                     console.log(item.get_item("Value"));
                }
                console.log('Tu puntos son: ' + counter);
                document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = counter + ' Points';
           },
           onRequestFailed
      );
 },onRequestFailed);

 function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
     alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }
```

Note that this requires *two* asynchronous calls: one to get the view XML and another to actually get the items.

Comment: Where I'm supposed to introduce the name of my list view? Still getting the entire items of the list, not filter. The list name is 'My Recognitions' and the view is 'CurrentUser'.